# Can't start MAK debug server on eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to start **MAK** debug server on eclipse,but it failed to start for current **MAK** user.

Please note, I'm using LAWSON old plugin not INFOR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that debug mode is enabled=1 from lifecycle manager ..just right click on your environment ..edit properities..search for debug..set it to 1

[image]